# How to call Javascript function from thymeleaf th:text attribute?

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to make my language selector display flags instead of language names

I have my flags.js file, which contains the following info

```
let flags = [
    {
        "code": "AD",
        "emoji": "",
        "unicode": "U+1F1E6 U+1F1E9",
        "name": "Andorra",
        "title": "flag for Andorra"
    },
    ...
];

let getFlagByCountryCode = (countryCode) => {
    flags.find((flag) => {
        return flag.code === countryCode.toUpperCase();
    })
};
```

And I have my thymeleaf rendered `select` for languages

```
<select title="Language" id="locales" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px;">
    <th:block th:each="locale : ${@resourceService.getLocales()}">
        <option th:value="${locale.language}"
                th:text="'getFlagByCountryCode(' + ${locale.language} + ')'"
                th:selected="${locale.language}==${T(org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder).getLocale().language}">
        </option>
    </th:block>
</select>
```

But instead of calling the JS function, it just displays the value as text

Comment: As far as I know, you can't call js function inside `th:text` .what you can do is call your js function when page loads and prepare your select options according to your needs and then put it in your `select` tag by id/class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript in thymeleaf by using  tag in thymeleaf page.Let me show you one example:
This is my HTML page:

```
<input id="ok" type="submit"   onclick="redirection()"/>
```

You can use javascript as:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

"Your java script code"

```
</script>
```